# Using python Django, how do I return a google protobuff object as a response?

Tags: django, protocol-buffers, bitcoin

I'm ultimately aiming to create a payment request object for bitcoin, bip 70 in particular because I would like to capture a valid return address but I'm not sure of the correct method to return a protobuff response object using Django.

```
import payments_pb2
x = payments_pb2
x.address = 'home'
return render_to_response(x)
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Protocol buffer is a binary format. You can serve protocol buffer content from django in a similar way to serving pictures, files ...

Code example:

```
def protobuf_view(request):
    ...

    x = payments_pb2
    x.address = 'home'

    return HttpResponse(x.SerializeToString(), content_type="application/octet-stream")
```